# How to clear the text in a Material-UI Autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an `Autocomplete` field which uses:

```
searchText = {this.state.searchText}
```

like this;

```
<AutoComplete
  floatingLabelText='agent input'
  ref='agentInput'
  hintText="type response"
  multiLine = {true}
  fullWidth = {true}
  searchText = {this.state.searchText}
  onNewRequest={this.sendAgentInput}
  dataSource={this.agentCommands}
/>
```

But when I update the `this.setState({searchText: null })`
it will clear the autoComplete once, but not the second time.

Not sure if this is a bug or if there's another way to reset the field.

I also tried looking for the field and adding a `ref` but no luck.

Filed here in case it's a bug
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/2615

Comment: Can you add a fiddle for this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try also to change *searchText* on every input update:

```
onUpdateInput={this.handleUpdateInput}
```

This function should change *searchText* whenever user changes the input:

```
handleUpdateInput(text) {
  this.setState({
    searchText: text
  })
}
```

My code looks as follows (ES6):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.dataSource = ['a', 'b' ,'c']
    this.state = {
        searchText: ''
    }

  }

  handleUpdateInput (t) { this.setState({ searchText: t }) }

  handleSelect (t) { this.setState( { searchText: '' }) }

  render () {
    return <AutoComplete dataSource={this.dataSource}
                         searchText={this.state.searchText}
                         onNewRequest={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
                         onUpdateInput={this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this)}
    />
  }      
}
```

Here I want to clear input when user presses enter or chooses some item from the list (so I clear *searchText* in *handleSelect*) but I also change state of *searchText* on every input update (*handleUpdateInput*).

I hope it will work for you!

Comment: a few months back, but thanks for the reply! I'll check it out.

Comment: This is not working since they add close menu timeout

Comment: With the new menuCloseDelay property, an alternative is to setTimeout when clearing the searchText for a delay equal to the default (300, or whatever you set for the delay).

Comment: Anyone interested in /why/ you need the onUpdateInput handler.  `state.searchText` is `''`.  It never changes from that - you enter text into the box/make a selection, and the prop is updated.  You then try to trigger the state to change/text to reset to `''`, but it was already that value.  So, nothing happens.  `onUpdateInput` handler above makes sure the Component's state.searchText tracks the current input value.  Then when you set to `''`, the change is detected and actually actioned.

Comment: There is no prop like `searchText` or anything mentioned while defining `<Autocomplete/>` in the docs. Maybe you are referring to anything equivalent available

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
this.setState({ searchText: "\r" });
```

because I think the function should test the length of the string (BUG ?)

Answer (score 1):

For [freesolo `Autocomplete`](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#free-solo), you can control the `inputValue` of `Autocomplete` and set it to an empty string on demand:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

return (
  <>
    <Button onClick={() => setInputValue('')}>clear input</Button>
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={(_, v) => setInputValue(v)}
      options={top100Films}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
  </>
);
```

If you also want to change the currently selected value, not just the value in the input box:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

return (
  <>
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        setInputValue('');
        setValue(null);
      }}
    >
      clear input
    </Button>
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo
      value={value}
      onChange={(_, v) => setValue(v)}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={(_, v) => setInputValue(v)}
      options={top100Films}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
  </>
);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]